# Does wearing jewelry increase chance of static electricity

Tags: electrostatics

I am the only one in my office repeatedly subject to static stock. Does wearing silver jewelry increase my chance of getting a shock?

Comment: Do you shuffle your feet more than most people?

Comment: Talk about a straight line!  :-) . Anyway, metal jewelry provides more chance that any static you're carrying will discharge on contact w/ ground.  Meanwhile, relax: you're safe from vampires.

Comment: no i do not shuffle my feet.

Comment: And its a wood floor, on top of that i wear heels - you try shuffling your feet in heels.

Answer (score 4):

It's unlikely.

Stack charge builds up when two insulators rub against each other. This could be between your shoes and the carpet, for instance. You may be wearing shoes with soles with different materials, or walk in a way that picks up charge more easily.
Silver is a conductor, so doesn't cause static build-up.
The charge is later discharged when you touch something grounded, causing the shock.